# how can authenticate a client on a different machine on a WebAPI with a user from WebAPI's domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Web Api 2.2 with Windows Authentication enabled.

And also, I have a client with .NET Framework 4.0 to connect to this WebAPI:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};

// Llamar al servicio web para obtener los códigos.
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
}
```

But the client will run in a computer that it isn't on the same domain than the web api.

Is `UseDefaultCredentials = true` enought or do I have to pass user, password and domain to the web service?

Comment: just to clarify, will the webapi have access to the AD?

Comment: I don't see how a client machine is going to use Windows authentication if the web server is on a different domain. What would the server do with the client credentials sent through, since it wouldn't recognize them?

Comment: @OliGray setting a network credentials with user, password and domain name.

Comment: But the question is: how can authenticate a client on a different machine on a WebAPI with a user from WebAPI's domain?

Comment: I understand the question, but we need to know some things that don't make sense. Is the WebAPI responsible for the authentication? If so, you should not have the client do the authentication in the AD.

However if you want, you can do the authentication on the client, then, via client call the database on your webAPI to see if there is a user with that name allowed into your webAPI. It's one way.

Comment: Yes, I have test it and `UseDefaultCredentials = true` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

IIS is going to try and authenticate the HTTP request coming in using Windows Authentication and it's going to fail because the box is on a different domain. None of your server side code is going to execute. Take a look at the HTTP request/response flow in Fiddler or a browsers developer tools to understand the process of Windows Authentication better.

You could create a page on the server with anonymous access enabled which could run some authentication code but you'd need to consider how you're going to send the username and password over securely...